# Optimal filter for different resolution measurements

Tags: adc, signal-processing, resolution

I will try to be brief and simple. (that are not my cualities)

Introduction :

I have to plot a signal that at the beginning has a big value, let say 60V and then the signal stays near 4V.

The signal is measured by 2 “12bits-ADC” (0V to 3V):

The first channel has a gain of 3V/60V = 0.05V/V (So it could measure the entire range)

The second channel has à gain of 3/10V = 0.3V/V and saturates the signal at 3 volts to avoid to damage the ADC.

I did that because my resolution is very poor in the 4V zone if I use the entire range to measure the signal and I need the BW, so I can use filtering to increase the number of bits. There is also another reason, the system has a lot of noise, so the SNR with a gain of 0.05V is ok for signals over 10V but it is not enough for signal under 10V.

Question:

There is an optimal filter/algorithm to use the 2 measurement with different resolutions to build the signal/plot? I would like to avoid transitions distortion near the 10V region.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the large BW channel to measure/sample the signal.  If the signal drops below 10v, then enable the lower range channel and now take the samples from this channel.  As the signal goes over 10v, disable the lower range channel and go back to taking the samples from the large BW channel.